# Django-Debug-Toolbar not showing(disallowed MIME type)

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

i install django-debug-toolbar 3.2.2 and configure it step by step by [Installation Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) 

my templates is just `hello.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

at the end, when i type `python manage.py runserver`
Django Debug Toolbar not show up.
but in concole i see this
`Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/plain”).`

- python 3.8.8(base on anaconda)
- Django 3.2.7
- windows 10

what's going on?

Answer (score 9):

this work for me!
in settings.py

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS": False,
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I'm using Django 3.2.8 and django-debug-toolbar 3.2.2 and after following the instructions found here https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html exactly as they are written, it wasn't until I applied this code to my settings.py file that it finally started working. Thank you, this took me a while before I found your solution and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try including static files in urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    
    urlpatterns = [
        # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**OR**

Try changing the version of django-debug-toolbar. I had the same problem on django-debug-toolbar-3.1.1 and just switched to 2.2 and it worked